# evaluating a bash command with if

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements, evaluate

i am looking to create a delete query that is going to get sent to a database.

I really don't have a model for doing so, so I look for the key word delete in the 
/bigcompany/scripts/dbscripts/ directory and see how others have done it.

When i use this i get a whole bunch of good examples, but it does not give me the names of the scripts :

```
cat /bigcompany/scripts/dbscripts/* | grep delete
```

I would like to know the name of the script that has the delete line query, so I can see the query in the context of the script.

I tried :

```
for i in $(ls /bigcompany/scripts/dbscripts/ )
do 
if [ cat /bigcompany/scripts/dbscripts/$i | grep delete ] 
   then
   echo $i
   fi 
done
```

I was thinking if "cat /bigcompany/scripts/dbscripts/ | grep delete" evaluated to successful, the script would echo the script name that contained the keyword.

However it does not.

Comment: `if grep -q delete "/bigcompany/scripts/$i"` -- no need for `[ ]` here at all.

Comment: also, `for i in /bigcompany/scripts/dbscripts/*` -- no `ls` involved.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for a general introduction for why `ls` should never be used in scripts, except when displaying filesystem listings to the user (or placing them in logs for later human consumption).

Comment: Also. `echo "$i"`, not `echo $i` -- otherwise, you'll find the results to be... surprising... when you have a file named like `foo * bar.sql`.

Comment: UUOC -- Useless Use Of `cat`: use `grep delete "$DBSCRIPTS/$i"` (where you assign `DBSCRIPTS=/bigcompany/scripts/dbscripts` and then use the variable to avoid repetition).

Comment: SO basically  - i was am doing grep wrong.  - nice work guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a list of the file names containing matches, so use `-l` to do that (all in one fell swoop, which has the additional merit of avoiding problems with blanks and other oddball characters in the file names):

```
grep -l delete /bigcompany/scripts/dbscripts/*
```

If you're dealing with SQL, unless there's a strong standard to the contrary, you probably want to recognize DELETE too, so add `-i` (for case-insensitive):

```
grep -l -i delete /bigcompany/scripts/dbscripts/*
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason there are no filenames is because you con`cat`enate them all into one file. If you let `grep` search them individually, it'll show the individual filenames:

```
grep delete /bigcompany/scripts/dbscripts/*
```

Comment: Oh, OK; I'll remove my comment and you can remove your response.

Answer (score 1):

Grep has the `-H` option which prints the file name for each match.  As an alternative you can use the `-l` option which only prints the file names of matches rather than the matching text.